# mongoose is giving error invalid type on findById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm, nosql

I am new to node js, I was trying to get user from Mongo db with mongoose but it is giving me error. THis is my UserScheme in `db.js`:

```
const config = require('config');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect(config.get('mongo.uri'));
mongoose.set('debug', config.get('app.verbose') === true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

const UserSchema = new Schema({
       phone             : String,
       shortPhone        : String,
       password          : String,
       averageRating     : Number,
       profile           : {
               email        : String,
               mainlyHereFor: String,
               enabledVideoResume: {type: Boolean, default: false},
               seekingOpportunityType: String,
               fullName     : String,
               username     : String,
               address      : {
                       city   : {type: String, default: 'Unknown'},
                       state  : String,
                       country: String,
                       zip    : String
               },
      }
}

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The user is being created, but when I am trying to find the user by id with mongoose it is giving me some `invalid type` error:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db');

router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  db.User.findById('5f20ec88d5cf2f2994bc42d4') // req.user.id)
    .then((user) => {
      let connsFilter = user.connections.filter((conn) => conn.relationship == 'connected');
      const users = connsFilter.map((conn) => conn.user);

      let query = {
        'connections.user': { $in: users }
      };

      return db.User.find(query)
        .select('-contacts')
        .populate({ path: 'jobs', match: { spam: false } });
    })
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ status: 'bad', error: err });
    });
});
```

Clicking on db.User always takes me to the definition of User schema but it still goes to the catch block, even if this user exists in my database.

Comment: try changing `'connections.user': { $in: users }` to `'connections.user': { '$in': 'users' }`

Comment: Try casting userId. userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that
db.User.findById(ObjectId('5f20ec88d5cf2f2994bc42d4')),
you have to use ObjectId if ur _id is object_id instead of normal string